# Create pause menu in Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift4

I am trying to create a pause menu on the game layer. I'm doing this just by adding two buttons on top when the pause button is pressed so the player can still see the stage of the game

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(location).name == "pause" {
            let button: SKSpriteNode?
            let button2: SKSpriteNode?

            button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button_continue")
            button?.name = "button_continue"
            button?.size.height = 55
            button?.size.width = 215
            button?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: button!.size)
            button?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            button?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 160)
            button?.zPosition = 100
            self.addChild(button!)

            button2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button_finish")
            button2?.name = "button_finish"
            button2?.size.height = 55
            button2?.size.width = 215
            button2?.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: button2!.size)
            button2?.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            button2?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -50)
            button2?.zPosition = 100
            self.addChild(button2!)

            // The two buttons are created but here I am trying to stop everything until the continue button is pressed and I don't find a way
        } 
    }
}
```

I have tried sleep() or timer.invalidate() but neither of them work with if statements, and I can't use while loops because then buttons don't appear until the while loop finishes:

```
while atPoint(location).name != "button_cotinue" {
    timer1.invalidate()
}
```

That is what I tried and doesn't work.

Then when the continue button is pressed I will also delete the buttons but I can code that correctly. As well the finish button sends the player to the main menu scene.

Comment: You really should change your title to something like "Pausing Timers in Spritekit" your title is misleading. Pausing a game and creating a Pause menu within Spritekit is usually handled with the .isPaused property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I do is put the controls (buttons) in a layer named `controlsLayer` that is separate from all of the game play items such as player, enemies and obstacles. Then I put all of the game items that I want to be paused in a layer named `gameLayer`. I make the `controlsLayer` have a high `zPosition` like 100.

then when I click my pause button I call `gameLayer.isPaused = true` and when I click continue I would call the opposite. `gameLayer.isPaused = false`. by just pausing the gameLayer, you can still run other actions like transitions or effects on your pause buttons. If you pause the whole scene you won't be able to run any actions or effects on any items.

Comment: The view stops but I am having a problem with some timers which I can't stop. I thought it was because the target was "self",  I changed it to gameLayer and it was even worst. So how can I stop them?

Comment: you don't show any timers in your code!. this is why timers shouldn't be used in Spritekit IMO. there are literally dozens of comments/posts throughout the Spritekit questions talking about the disadvantage of using Timers in SpriteKit

Comment: Sorry, I am new with swift and didn't know that, already changed it and now is working perfectly. Ps: I had to add `addChild(controlLayer)` and then `removeFromParent`.

Comment: if my comment helped you answer your question you should mark it as correct